# Как узнать, что статья добавлена в закладки?

Tags: laravel

Таблицы:

**posts**

**users**

**posts_user** - промежуточная - закладки

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('post_id');
```

Вывожу все статьи

```
$allPosts = Posts::with('users')->get();
```

---

```
Class Posts extends Model
{
    //получить автора статьи

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Не знаю, что надо сделать, что бы к запросу ещё добавить ключ, что бы
в цикле потом выводить, что статья уже добавлена, иначе добавить в закладки.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого обратитесь к свойству `$pivot`, он всегда есть по умолчанию, то есть чтобы получить `posts_user.id` просто нужно:

```
foreach($post->users as $user) {
    $id = $user->pivot->id;
}
```

Так же можно к реляции дописать метод `withPivot` и указать какие только поля нужно выводить:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');->withPivot('id');
```